gaussian process classification, deriving posterior for latent variable
Context
I'm currently studying classification using gaussian processes.
It's all described in https://gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW3.pdf.
I'm stuck with understanding and proving the probabilities 3.9 and 3.10 in there (this question will be focused on 3.9, another one is asked specifically for 3.10: gaussian process classification, deriving posterior for label).
The problem is modeled like this (if I got everything right):

$X$ are $N$ measures in $\mathbb{R}^D$
$Y$ are the $N$ corresponding
binary labels (at this stage, we're dealing with a simple 2 classes
problem).

Now it gets fuzzy. AFAIU:
$p\left(Y|X\right)=\sigma\left(f\left(X\right)\right)$ where $f$ is an unknown function $\mathbb{R}^D\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ and $\sigma$ a fixed, strictly increasing, bijective, function $\mathbb{R}\mapsto\left[0;1\right]$
$f$ is also named a latent variable (a hidden function of the measure that, hopefully, makes the classification process easier).
The label are said to be generated independently conditional on $f\left(x\right)$ but I'm not sure how to interpret it.
My assumption would be: $p\left(Y|f\left(X\right),X\right)=\prod_{i=1}^N p\left(y_i|f\left(x_i\right),x_i\right)$.
Now $f$ is unknown but it is modeled as having some regularity, using gaussian processes. Thus $f$ can be seen, a priori, as a random variable such that if $F$ are the $N$ values $f\left(x_i\right)$:
$p\left(F|X\right)=\mathcal{N}_F\left(\mu,K\left(X\right)\right)$
Where $\mathcal{N}_F$ denotes a multivariate normal law, with variable $F$, mean $\mu$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$ and $K\left(X\right)$ a definite positive matrix.
So the idea is that a measure $x$ and gives a probability $\sigma\left(f\left(x\right)\right)$ of having $y=+1$. But this probability is itself a random variable because f is here random and has only some regularity modeled as a gaussian process.
Now we want to go for a supervised classification, using observations $\{X,Y\}$ in order to get an estimate of $p\left(y_*|x_*,X,Y\right)$ for a new sample.
The issue in this situation is that the function $f$ that models $p\left(Y|X\right)$ is itself unknow and our knowledge of it only improves indirectly from accumulated observations.
latent function posterior
The first stage of this process results in the equation 3.9 in above reference:
$p\left(f_*|x_*,X,Y\right)=\int_F p\left(f_*|x_*,X,F\right)p\left(F|X,Y\right)dF$
This is the first equation I'd like to prove
Though it seems natural I'm failing to untangled $X\leftrightarrow Y\leftrightarrow F$ inter-dependencies correctly to reach this result.
I started by the obvious, going to $p\left(f_*,x_*,X,Y\right)$ with Bayes rule and then marginalizing: $p\left(f_*|x_*,X,Y\right)=\frac{\int_F p\left(f_*,F,x_*,X,Y\right)dF}{p\left(x_*,X,Y\right)}=\frac{\int_F p\left(f_*|F,x_*,X,Y\right)p\left(F,x_*,X,Y\right)dF}{p\left(x_*,X,Y\right)}=\int_F p\left(f_*|F,x_*,X,Y\right)p\left(F|X,Y\right)dF$
(using the additional hypothesis that the next sample point $x_*$ is independent from previous observations) but I don't know how I can get $Y$ to disappear, leaving only a condition on $x_*,X,F$

[IDEA] I'd like to use the conditional independence to write that $p\left(f_*,Y,x_*,X,F\right)=p\left(f_*,Y|x_*,X,F\right)p\left(x_*,X,F\right)=p\left(f_*|x_*,X,F\right)p\left(Y|x_*,X,F\right)p\left(x_*,X,F\right)$.
Which could lead to the desired result. But it's an intuition, not a clean mathematical argument.

In order to prove the formula, I need to reinterpret the original document hypothesis.
In partial support of this reinterpretation, there is a paper from the same author: Assessing Approximations for Gaussian Process Classification.
The detailed hypotheses are the following:

labels distribution depend only on the latent function of the measure and not on the measure itself: $p\left(Y|F,X\right)=p\left(Y|F\right)$.
labels distribution depend only on the latent function of the measure and not on the latent functions of other samples: $p\left(y_i|F\right)=p\left(y_i|f_i\right)$.
labels are conditionaly independent given F: $p\left(Y|F\right)=\prod_{i}p\left(y_i|F\right)$.
From 2 and 3 we've got: $p\left(Y|F\right)=\prod_{i}p\left(y_i|f_i\right)$ which is the hypothesis explicited in the mentioned paper.
Eventually, adding 1, we've got:
$p\left(Y|F,X\right)=p\left(Y|F\right)=\prod_{i}p\left(y_i|f_i\right)$.

Then, let's prove that $p\left(f_*|F,x_*,X,Y\right)=p\left(f_*|F,x_*,X\right)$
$p\left(f_*|F,x_*,X,Y\right)=\frac{p\left(f_*,F,x_*,X,Y\right)}{p\left(F,x_*,X,Y\right)}$
$p\left(f_*,F,x_*,X,Y\right)=\sum_{y_*}p\left(y_*,Y,f_*,F,x_*,X\right)$
Using 4: $p\left(y_*,Y,f_*,F,x_*,X\right)=p\left(y_*,Y|f_*,F,x_*,X\right)p\left(f_*,F,x_*,X\right)=p\left(y_*|f_*\right)p\left(Y|F\right)p\left(f_*,F,x_*,X\right)$
Thus: $p\left(f_*,F,x_*,X,Y\right)=\sum_{y_*}p\left(y_*|f_*\right)p\left(Y|F\right)p\left(f_*,F,x_*,X\right)=p\left(Y|F\right)p\left(f_*,F,x_*,X\right)\sum_{y_*}p\left(y_*|f_*\right)$
And: $p\left(f_*,F,x_*,X,Y\right)=p\left(Y|F\right)p\left(f_*,F,x_*,X\right)$
Then: $p\left(f_*|F,x_*,X,Y\right)=\frac{p\left(Y|F\right)p\left(f_*,F,x_*,X\right)}{p\left(F,x_*,X,Y\right)}=\frac{p\left(Y|F\right)p\left(f_*|F,x_*,X\right)p\left(F,x_*,X\right)}{p\left(F,x_*,X,Y\right)}$
As new samples measures are independent from previous ones, $p\left(F,x_*,X\right)=p\left(x_*\right)p\left(F,X\right)$ and $p\left(F,x_*,X,Y\right)=p\left(x_*\right)p\left(F,X,Y\right)$, Thus $\frac{p\left(F,x_*,X,Y\right)}{p\left(F,x_*,X\right)}=\frac{p\left(F,X,Y\right)}{p\left(F,X\right)}=p\left(Y|F,X\right)=p\left(Y|F\right)$ (from 1)
Which gives $p\left(f_*|F,x_*,X,Y\right)=p\left(f_*|F,x_*,X\right)$
Within the question we went as far as $p\left(f_*|x_*,X,Y\right)=\int_F p\left(f_*|F,x_*,X,Y\right)p\left(F|X,Y\right)dF$ and now we can conclude that
$p\left(f_*|x_*,X,Y\right)=\int_F p\left(f_*|F,x_*,X\right)p\left(F|X,Y\right)dF$
Which is the expected formula.
If a simpler proof is possible, please provide it as another answer.
